# Swagger поля для отправки запроса

Tags: django, swagger

Делаю авто документацию при помощи django swagger. Заметил такую вещь, что некоторые запросы имеют поле для ввода, например тут поле  id имеет отдельную форму

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А некоторые функции таких полей не имеют

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это зависит от способа передачи параметра в запросе. Например, если у параметра значение `in` равно `path`, то вы увидите поле ввода. Если же равно `body`, то будет отображена модель данных. Чтобы редактировать данные в модели, нажмите кнопку `Try it out`.

Например, ваш первый запрос, скорее всего, выглядит так:

```
/user/{id}
  get:
    summary: ""
    parameters:
    - name: "id"
      in: "path"
      required: true
      description: "A unique integer value identifying this user"
```

Второй запрос выглядит примерно так:

```
/user/password
  patch:
    summary: ""
    parameters:
    - in: "body"
      name: "data"
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: "/#/definitions/SomeModel"
```

Отобразить поля в веб-интерфейсе Swagger не получится, так как модели данных бывают очень сложными, в них бывают вложенные объекты, поля различных типов, массивы, и в общем случае их отображение - задача затруднительная. А вообще в терминологии HTTP и REST API всё, что находится в поле data - это одно поле - тело HTTP-запроса.

Кстати, поле id недоступно для ввода, пока вы не нажмёте кнопку `Try it out`.

Comment: А есть возможность все же сделать поля?